# Ruby regex search and replace array

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex

I've got an array with a list of image URLs that I'm trying to search/replace with a regex (via gsub). The values are in the format //subdomain.website.com/folder/image.extension. I want to add 'https' in front of each array entry.

I've tried to use gsub, but the array remains unchanged:

```
matches = source.scan(/(\/\/\w+\.\w+\.\w{2,4}\/\w+\/\w+\.\w{2,4})/).uniq
matches.each {|value| value.to_s.gsub!(/\/\//, 'https://')}
```

In Perl, I could do something like this to change each value:

```
for (@matches) {
    s/\/\//https:\/\//g;
}
```

Am I calling the gsub function in an incorrect manner?

Comment: Don't use regex to modify URLs, instead use the URI class to parse them, then change the `scheme`. See [the example](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Generic.html#method-i-scheme-3D-label-Usage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I find it strange that you are calling `to_s` on `value`, since `value` is an array which will include array notation when converted to a string, so `value.to_s` might look something like `["//subdomain.website.com/folder/image.exte"]`.

You can avoid this by changing your regex to not include a capture group:

```
/\/\/\w+\.\w+\.\w{2,4}\/\w+\/\w+\.\w{2,4}/
```

Now to the main part of your question, you should be calling [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) on `matches`, instead of `each`. The `map` method will change each element in the array to the result of calling the supplied block with the given element.

Put together it might look like this:

```
matches = source.scan(/\/\/\w+\.\w+\.\w{2,4}\/\w+\/\w+\.\w{2,4}/).uniq
matches.map { |value| value.gsub(/\/\//, 'https://') }
# => ["https://subdomain.website.com/folder/image.exte"]
```

Comment: Thank you. I was under the impression that I needed a capture group to save the regex matches. Now I know. Also, I found it necessary to use `gsub!` in place of `gsub` to successfully change the array values.

Answer (score 0):

If you know every element of your array is formatted properly and ready to have `"https:"` prepended, it seems like concatenating would be simpler than gsub. For example,

```
matches.map! { |value| "https:" << value }
```

should work once you have an array of strings as described by @August.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
matches.map{|m| "https#{m}"}
```

This should add https to the front of every element.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby comes with a nice class for this called [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html), so take advantage of it:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('//www.example.com')  # => #<URI::Generic:0x007ff0098581e8 URL://www.example.com>
uri.scheme = 'https'                  # => "https"
uri.to_s                              # => "https://www.example.com"
```

If you want to process a list of URLs:

```
%w[
  //www.example.com
].map{ |url|                          # => ["//www.example.com"]
  uri = URI.parse(url)                # => #<URI::Generic:0x007ff009853350 URL://www.example.com>
  uri.scheme = 'https'                # => "https"
  uri.to_s                            # => "https://www.example.com"
}                                     # => ["https://www.example.com"]
```

The advantage of URI is it's smart enough to do the right thing if the URL already has a scheme or is missing it entirely:

```
require 'uri'

%w[
  http://foo.com
  https://foo.com
  //foo.com
].map { |url|
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  uri.scheme = 'https'
  uri.to_s 
} # => ["https://foo.com", "https://foo.com", "https://foo.com"]
```

If you *insist* on using a regex, then simplify it:

```
url = '//www.example.com'
url[/^/] = 'https:'
url # => "https://www.example.com"
```

And:

```
%w[
  //www.example.com
].map{ |url|           # => ["//www.example.com"]
  url[/^/] = 'https:'  # => "https:"
  url                  # => "https://www.example.com"
}                      # => ["https://www.example.com"]
```

Using a regular expression isn't smart enough to sense whether the scheme already exists, so more code has to be written to handle that situation.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: do other languages (PHP/Python/Perl) have similar functionality as the URI class in Ruby? For example, I know Python has `urllib.parse`, though it does not seem capable of changing a URI's scheme.